# passing a class to create a new object in method

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, parameter-passing

I am new to programming and I don know whether it is possible to pass a class to a method.

My aim in doing this would be to create a new Array of objects by copying an already existing one by using an accessor to get an already existing one and copying it to a new array.

However My problem is they fact that I cannot create a new array without telling the method what objects are to be stored in that array.

I want it as a method as I am aiming to reuse the method for multiple object types.

```
public class MusicCollection {
    private Cassette[] cassetteArray = new Cassette[10];

     public Cassette[] getCassetteArray() {
        return cassetteArray;
        }
    }
```

Assuming that I store objects in the array successfully I then wish to.

```
    fm.writeFile(outputFileName, mc.getCassetteArray(), Cassette,
            "\n",",");
```

To this function so that I can create a duplicate of the array there.

```
   public void writeFile (String fileName, Object inputArray, Class Class,
                           String newLineDelimiter, String commaSeperator){

        Class[] c = mc.getCassetteArray();
```

Also just thought that I would state that I have have a cassette class create cassette objects and then storing them in MusicCollection.

mc is an object of MusicCollection and is accessible within the scope.

[EDIT]
I am sorry about the confusion here. I am not able to show anymore code as I have not figured out how to even start.

What the writeFile method is going to do is to get an Array of objects. In this case I want to pass it an Array of Cassettes. I then want to with this array of cassettes go through each object individually and then write this to a csv.

I have a accessor in the Cassette method that puts all the values into an array in which I can then use FileWriter to iterate through and write. 
However If I just import the array I cannot call the accessor from the Cassette object for some reason.

Perhaps Adding the class in not neccessary and after much thought I dont think it is. However I cannot call the methods from the "inputArray" in the above code.

Comment: What do you need done? The question is unclear to me.

Comment: Because I multiple versions of the cassette I wish to make the method "writeFile" to work for different objects and not just class. The method itself aims to save the array of objects into a csv. My issue is that I cannot pass the class and the above code does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot pass and the code does not work? can you be more specific

Comment: pass cassette as `objects` then use `instanceof`... `Class Class` in your params is an error since `Class` is a keyword

Comment: There is no use of line `Class[] c = mc.getCassetteArray();` What you wanna do with this ? Because If you want to iterate you can do that without using this line.
Also provide entire `writeFile()` method.

Comment: I have added an edit trying to explain better. I am sorry about all this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to programming and I don know whether it is possible to pass a class to a  method.
>
> My aim in doing this would be to create a new Array of objects by copying an already existing one by using an accessor to get an already existing one and copying it to a new array.

```
 public void <T> T[] createNewArrayOfClass(Class<T> clazz, int length){
    return (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
}
```

Hope it helps.